# How to Define a Constant Value of a User-defined Type in Go?

Tags: go

I am implementing a bit-vector in Go:

```
// A bit vector uses a slice of unsigned integer values or “words,”
// each bit of which represents an element of the set.
// The set contains i if the ith bit is set.
// The following program demonstrates a simple bit vector type with these methods.
type IntSet struct {
    words []uint64 //uint64 is important because we need control over number and value of bits
}
```

I have defined several *methods* (e.g. membership test, adding or removing elements, set operations like union, intersection etc.) on it which all have a pointer receiver. Here is one such method:

```
// Has returns true if the given integer is in the set, false otherwise
func (this *IntSet) Has(m int) bool {
   // details omitted for brevity
}
```

Now, I need to return an empty set that is a true constant, so that I can use the *same* constant every time I need to refer to an `IntSet` that contains no elements. One way is to return something like `&IntSet{}`, but I see two disadvantages:

- Every time an empty set is to be returned, a new value needs to be allocated.
- The returned value is not really constant since it can be modified by the callers.

How do you define a *null set* that does not have these limitations?

Answer (score 1):

If you read https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants you see that constants are limited to basic types. A struct or a slice or array will not work as a constant.

I think that the best you can do is to make a function that returns a copy of an internal empty set. If callers modify it, that isn't something you can fix.

Actually modifying it would be difficult for them since the `words` inside the `IntSet` are lowercase and therefore private. If you added a value next to `words` like `mut bool` you could add a `if mut` check to every method that changes the `IntSet`. If it isn't mutable, return an error or panic.

With that, you *could* keep users from modifying constant, non-mutable `IntSet` values.

Comment: Perhaps I have to live with this _limitation_? Won't `words` be modifiable by other code in the same _package_?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Yes but why would you do that? You can place all of that code in a new directory and make it into its own module. Then no methods can change `words` except ones you write.